# How to stop <mat-expansion-panel> from triggering with spacebar?

Tags: html, angular, input, material-design

I have a mat-accordion with a textarea box in the panel-description. When I am tying in the text area and hit spacebar it opens/closes the panel. How can I stop this?

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      Header
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-description>
      <mat-form-field>
        <textarea matInput></textarea>
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: There is not input box in the header in your markup. Can you edit the question to include it?

Comment: Yeah, I meant text-area and panel-description, although the problem is the same regardless of whether it's in the header or description area

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with a textarea in the header but not in the description.

Comment: For me it's doing it in both, so I'm sure the solution would likely be the same.

Comment: won't it be the correct way to have the mat-panel-description inside the mat-expansion-panel-header? Actually i don't know if this solves anything but this looks wrong

Answer (score 12):

I found one solution more clean. Only add to panel-header this for override keydown event SPACE:

```
(keydown.Space)="$event.stopImmediatePropagation();"
```

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header (keydown.Space)="$event.stopImmediatePropagation();">
```

Ref:
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/expansion/expansion-panel-header.ts

Comment: I always talk against adding logic to the template. However, this solution is fantastic. No need for an additional function in the controller and no conditional code needed to only focus the spacebar. Nice work.

Comment: On my side to get it work it was:  
`<mat-panel-title (keydown.Space)="$event.stopPropagation()">`

Comment: Excellent info!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use this shorter version:

```
<div (keydown.Space)="$event.stopPropagation()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You do something like this in your html,

```
<mat-accordion>
 <mat-expansion-panel>
  <div (keydown)="handleSpacebar($event)">
   /*this div should contain elements inside of the mat-expansion-panel
   where you would like to stop the propagation of the space key press*/             
  </div>
 </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

The function in the .js will be as so,

```
handleSpacebar(ev) {
 if (ev.keyCode === 32) {
   ev.stopPropagation();
 }
}
```

You can now use space in any of the element inside the div without causing the expansion panel to close. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

add `(keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"` to parent element

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
   .....
   </mat-expansion-panel-header>
   <div class="panel-body" (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
   ....
   </div>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```